# PHP: switching array values within while loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, while-loop

If I know that I'm only looping two times in a while loop, how do I switch array values after the first loop?

This is my array, $myarr:

```
Array ( // echo out array values from first loop
    [id1] => values_one
    [id2] => values_two
)

Array ( // echo out array values from second loop
    [id2] => values_two
    [id1] => values_one
)


$arr = array_values($myarr);
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 // ... more code
 //echo's out array values
   echo $arr[0]; //first loop should be values_one, second loop should be values_two
   echo $arr[1]; //first loop should be values_two, second loop should be values_one

}
```

Thank you

Comment: I feel like there's something missing...code...or better explanation of question.

Comment: yeah, he's loading $row with an assoc array an then doesn't use it. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a vague question, its difficult to be sure of 'edge cases'. But the below will solve your issue based upon what you have written above.

```
$arr = array_values($myarr);
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 // ... more code
 //echo's out array values
   echo $arr[0]; //first loop should be values_one, second loop should be values_two
   echo $arr[1]; //first loop should be values_two, second loop should be values_one
   $arr = array_reverse($arr, false);
}
```